# Refactoring leads to linker issue with duplicates

Tags: c++

I wish to have some wrapper code be a header-only library. I was inspired by the boost libraries to keep them header only to uncomplicate the need for distributing .lib's and including compiling .cpp's.

In this example "z.h" is the wrapper and a.cpp has been refactored to move B() into it's own source file. Now it doesn't work.

z.h

```
class Z
{
    public:
    void Foo(); // edited to match my code
};

Z::Foo() { }
```

a.cpp

```
#include "z.h"
void A() { 
      Z z;
      z.Foo();
}
//void B(Z z) {
//     z.Foo();
//}
```

b.cpp

```
#include "z.h"
void B(Z z) {           
      z.Foo();
}
```

*error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl void z::Foo()" already defined in b.obj*

I know I can fix this by separating out z.h into z.h for declarations and z.cpp for definitions.

- But how can Boost libraries get away without .cpp files?
- Does everything need to be a template?
- What code can go in z.h?

Comment: have you put include guards in your `.h` files?

Comment: Of course, I have. Include guards only help with compiling, not linking. (in visual studio, at least).

Comment: This code is fine. What does your *real* code look like? Perhaps implementing  Foo *outside* of the class declaration without marking it inline?

Comment: In that case, I see no obvious problem.

Comment: Foo is not being inlined for some reason. Among the possible causes is that you don't define the implementation of foo inside the class. You could try explicitly specifying the function as "inline"/

Comment: @BoPersson True, this is not my real code. I have headers including headers. I have both global functions and class methods making errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a moment, consider this header:

```
// foo.hpp

void foo(int x)
{
    /* do something */
}
```

(Header guards aren't relevent here, they work per-translation-unit.) We now have two translation units:

```
// a.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"
```

And:

```
// b.cpp

#include "foo.hpp"
```

What this ends up doing is defining `foo(int x)` twice, one in each TU. Multiple definitions are not allowed, under the One Definition Rule (ODR), and though technically no diagnostic is required, it's trivial on the compilers part to do so, and hence you get your error.

Luckily, there is a keyword, `inline`, which changes this behavior:

```
// foo.hpp

inline void foo(int x)
{
    /* do something */
}
```

This keyword tells the linker that, should it come across multiple definitions, it is free to pick a single definition and discard the rest. (It's up to you to make sure this is actually okay!) With this change, the previous ODR violation is solved and the program compiles.

Now, you've listed your header as:

```
class Z      
{      
    public:      
    void Foo(){       
       //do stuff      
    }      
};
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
class Z      
{      
    public:      
    void Foo();
};    

inline void Z::Foo(){       
       //do stuff      
    }
```

because functions that are defined within the class are implicitly `inline`. (This allows you to include the definition in multiple translation units without error.) I suspect what you've written is not what is in your post, but something like this:

```
class Z      
{      
    public:      
    void Foo();
};    

void Z::Foo(){       
       //do stuff      
    }
```

where `inline` is missing. The equivalence is lost, multiple definitions are created, and you violate the ODR.

The solution is to use `inline`, or implicitly use it by definition the function within the class definition. Personally, I find the latter much clearer (because you avoid repeating yourself), and much easier to maintain. Boost uses `inline` often to avoid the need for single definitions.

Comment: This sounds like a good explanation. I just need to see if this is the effect I want. Ideally, I'd like it to be identical to before by not inlining. I'm trying to find a pattern with **extern** possibly.

Comment: @BenL: `inline` doesn't mean the function gets inlined, that will always be up to the compiler, like it or not. This function still has external linkage. Internal linkage would be `static`.